# what is the color used in seekbar

Tags: android

I am trying to find the color code for the bright light blue color used by the Android framework in some of their widgets. I understand that the framework uses 9 patch images to draw these widgets, so the color code would theoretically not be stored in the framework code.

But is there a way to find what was the color code used in the SeekBar or the ToggleButton(the small blue line when Checked)?

Comment: I use `GIMP`'s color picker tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use `#33B5E5` for the color.

Comment: that's pretty damn accurate!

Comment: I agree. I have never found the color code, but using this it always matches the widgets that use the same color.

Comment: I found the framework colors at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml. Your code exactly matches `holo_blue_light`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot of the image and upload it to this site and click the color you want to know about.

http://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/

Comment: or use paint and pick color :D

Answer (score 0):

In Android-Studio you can do it in the Program itself too. To do that, follow this steps:

1. Put the Item in your view that you wish to know the color from or have a picture or screenshot ready and open on the PC
2. Select an item (Button, View, etc) in the "Component-Tree" on right side and go to the "Color-Property" or the prop "Backgroud" of the selected item (one has to be in Design-Mode to see the Component-Tree).
3. Then click the "..." behind the Property-Edittextfield and a menu opens up where you can choose a color, by either go to the System-Tab and choose a predefined Android-System Color (you see all the different greens here for example). After select a color you see the value of it in the value window below.
4. You can also go to the Color-Tab and click the little color-selector item, then hover it over the Layout-item that you draged to the view in step 1 and try to hover the spot where the needed color is. You can have also a screenshot open, or the android emulator or something. The color-picker lets you hover also over outside program views, not only insde Androidstudio.

Voila, there you have all system colors.